# Problem with imageStore in compute shader

Tags: opengl, compute-shader, opengl-4

I have a problem with a very simple compute shader that just copies a texture using imageStore.

```c
#define KS 16 // kernel size
layout (local_size_x = KS, local_size_y = KS) in;

layout(location = 0) uniform sampler2D u_inputTex;
layout(location = 1) uniform writeonly image2D u_outImg;

void main()
{
    const ivec2 gid = ivec2(gl_WorkGroupID.xy);
    const ivec2 tid = ivec2(gl_LocalInvocationID.xy);
    const ivec2 pixelPos = ivec2(KS) * gid + tid;

    imageStore(u_outImg, pixelPos,
        uvec4(255.0 * texelFetch(u_inputTex, pixelPos, 0).rgb, 255u));
}
```

In the C++ side, I have this:

```cpp
int w, h;
u32 inTex = -1;
{
    int nc;
    auto img = stbi_load("imgs/Windmill_NOAA.png", &w, &h, &nc, 3);
        
    if (img) {
        glGenTextures(1, &inTex);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, inTex);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        stbi_image_free(img);
    }
    else
        printf("Error loading img\n");
}

u32 outTex;
{
    glGenTextures(1, &outTex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outTex);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8UI, w, h);
}

u32 compProg = easyCreateComputeShaderProg("compute", shader_srcs::computeSrc);
glUseProgram(compProg);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, inTex);
glBindImageTexture(0, outTex, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA8UI);
glUniform1i(0, 0);
glUniform1i(1, 0);

glDispatchCompute((w+15)/16, (h+15)/16, 1);

glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT); // make sure the output image has been written
    
u8* img = new u8[w * h * 4];
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outTex);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
stbi_write_png("imgs/out.png", w, h, 1, img, w*4);
delete[] img;
```

The input image looks like this:

[image]

But this is what I get in the output image:

[image]

I simplified the shader further: instead of reading from the input texture, I just write a fixed value:

```c
    imageStore(u_outImg, pixelPos,
        //uvec4(255.0 * texelFetch(u_inputTex, pixelPos, 0).rgb, 255u));
        uvec4(1u));
```

I have noticed that:

- If I write 0 it's all black
- If I write 255 it's all white
- But if I write something in the middle (100 for example) it's not grey but white as well

I have also tried like this but didn't work either:

```c
    imageStore(u_outImg, pixelPos,
        vec4(texelFetch(u_inputTex, pixelPos, 0).rgb, 255u));
```

What I'm doing wrong? My end goal is to make a prostprocessing filter but I couldn't get it to work, so I tried to make it as simple as possible and yet it doesn't work.

Minimal example repo: https://github.com/tuket/stackoverflow_image_store_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8UI, w, h);
> ```

If you want to use an *unnormalized* unsigned integer image, you must declare it as `uimage2D` in the sahder. `image2D` is for floating-point or normalized integer (range `[0,1]`) only.

> ```
> glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);
> ```

That's the wrong memory barrier. The barrier is about how you're going to access the resources modified by your shader **after** the barrier, so the correct one is:

`GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT`

which is explained in the [reference page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMemoryBarrier.xhtml) as (emphasis mine):

> Writes to a texture via `glTex(Sub)Image*`, `glCopyTex(Sub)Image*`,
> `glCompressedTex(Sub)Image*`, **and reads via `glGetTexImage` after the
> barrier will reflect data written by shaders prior to the barrier.**
> Additionally, texture writes from these commands issued after the
> barrier will not execute until all shader writes initiated prior to
> the barrier complete.

Comment: It works, Thanks! Apart from that, I also had a mistake writing the image `stbi_write_png("imgs/out.png", w, h, 1, img, w*4);` -- The `1` should be a `0`.